# Render bands / bandData in jqplot when series contains null values

Tags: jqplot, confidence-interval

I am using jqplot to render a line graph.

My series data looks like:

```
results =[  
    ['1/1/2014', 1000],
    ['2/1/2014', 2000],
    ['3/1/2014', 3000],
    ['4/1/2014', 4000],
    ['5/1/2014', null]
];
```

my call to jqplot looks something like

```
$.jqplot('myChart', results, 
{
   series: [
        {
            rendererOptions: {
                bands: {
                    show: true,
                    interval: '10%'
                },
            }
        }
   ]
});
```

The chart will render, but it will be missing the 10% bands above and below.

If i change the null value
    ['5/1/2014', null]
to be
    ['5/1/2014', 5000]
then the bands will render correctly.

My does data have some missing values. Is there any way to make the bands render for non-null data points on the line, even if the line *does* have some null data points?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending null for those values, omit them entirely and depend on the [dateAxisRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html) to correctly space the values on the axis.

```
results = [
    ['1/1/2014', 1000],
    ['2/1/2014', 2000],
    ['3/1/2014', 3000],
    ['4/1/2014', 4000],
    ['6/1/2014', 3500]
];

$.jqplot ('myChart', [results],
{
    series: [{
        rendererOptions: {
            bands: {
                show: true,
                interval: '10%'                    
            }
        }
    }],
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
        }
    }
});
```

JSFiddle version here (don't forget the extra script reference for dateAxisRenderer)
http://jsfiddle.net/4vmNf/1/

Alternatively, you can pass separate arrays for upper & lower band data, and this does not have to follow the same intervals as the underlying data array.

```
lowerBand = [];
upperBand = [];

for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (results[i][1]) {
        lowerBand.push([results[i][0], results[i][1] * 0.9]);
        upperBand.push([results[i][0], results[i][1] * 1.1]);
    } else {
        // not clear to me how you want to calculate band for missing values
        lowerBand.push([results[i][0], 3500]);
        upperBand.push([results[i][0], 6500]);
    }
}
```

And then use `bandData` option:

```
series: [{
        rendererOptions: {
            bandData: [lowerBand, upperBand]
        }
    }]
```